# When JtextField get filled, JTable cell has to be filled. How to do it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, jtabbedpane

In my frame, I have a `JTable` and a `JTabbedPane`.

The `JTabbedPane` contains a `JTextField` for a Date.

When it is filled with a date and <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed, the "Date" column of the `JTable` has to be filled.

I have a method to check whether the text field contains a valid date or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with an `ActionListener`.

```
JTextField textField; // this is your text field
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        // Place your code to fill the JTable here.
        // Maybe something like:
        tableModel.setValueAt(textField.getText(), row, column);
    }
}
```

In the above example, make sure to reference `textField`, `row`, and `column` correctly.

---

**EDIT:** As MadProgrammer [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318540/when-jtextfield-get-filled-jtable-cell-has-to-be-filled-how-to-do-it#comment21627805_15318600), a `FocusListener` would provide an even broader implementation: whenever the text field loses focus, the code could be run. That would be implemented as follows:

```
textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
        // Place your code to fill the JTable here.
        // Maybe something like:
        tableModel.setValueAt(textField.getText(), row, column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `FocusListener` to that example and win a price...okay, an up-vote, but it's better then nothing ;)